# What can I consider a typo?

Tags: discussion, flags, typographical-error

Recently, I've been flagging quite a few questions as typos (*Not reproducible or was caused by a typo*). I would like to hear what the consensus is. Some examples are (albeit simplified and paraphrased):

One user asked why this raises an exception.

```python
a = [1, 2, 3]
num = input()
a.append(int(num))
print(a.index(num))
```

Which appends an integer but searches for a string.

Another user asked why they got different output for these two "seemingly equivalent" pieces of code.

```python
i = 0
while i < 10:
    print(a[i] - a[i+1])
```

```python
i = 0
j = i + 1
while i < 10:
    print(a[i] - a[j])
```

In which they forgot that `j` wasn't updated in the loop.

To me, it seems like they forgot a function call or single line of code, and that the user would be able to solve the problem and understand the issue with some simple debugging. I'd categorize these as typos as the answers are just *"You forgot X"*.

If not, how should I flag them considering these questions are also very specific to the user and not useful for other people?

Comment: You said yourself *"considering these questions are very specific to the user and not useful for other people*" and that is pretty much what the typo close reason says *"resolved in a way less likely to help future readers."*.If you think it won't help future users, by all means vote to close for that reason, if other users disagree then the post simply won't get closed for that reason and no harm is done.

Comment: Some "typo" Questions are very useful and go on to help a lot of users. Simply because even if they are simple to fix for experienced developers, new developers will search for the error message.

Comment: @GinoMempin Although, I'd say that the user clearly did understand that it returns a string, as they converted it to `int` when appending it to the list. But yes, in other cases where it's clear that that's the issue, I'd mark it as a duplicate.

Comment: The second case might be more appropriately closed as "needs more details" – if code is *obviously different*, then the assertion that it is "seemingly equivalent" just makes no sense without details. FWIW, adding the expectation that ``j = i + 1`` does make ``j`` an expression that is updated alongside ``i`` would make for a generally useful question that just happens to have an example – and admittedly countless duplicates.

Comment: To me, any error in the code _must_ not be corrected. The vast majority of bugs I've opened in my testing career were due to typos and copy/paste not going the right way. If the code is wrong, go ask the author to have a look at it, but do not touch it.

Comment: @DaemonPainter I agree, you should religiously avoid editing any code in questions. I'm a bit unsure though what this is a reference to? I'm not talking about editing the question.

Comment: To my mind, it's a typo if it's evident the OP wasn't asking about that specific issue.  If the answer is about issue X, but issue X isn't even mentioned anywhere in the title, then the question was *"resolved in a way less likely to help future readers."*  "Why does this raise an exception" doesn't mention indexing into an array using a string.  But they couldn't write that title, because they **forgot** that `num` is a string.  "Forgot" sounds very much like "typo" to me.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman you are right, I must have read this with my head under the sand. I'm part of the population who believe that typos _and_ misunderstanding of basic knowledge can indeed be the same. Although, the system can really work two ways around. Either you flag this and the community takes ownership how much common industry knowledge is the entry level for a question to exist, _or_ the community simply downvotes, and the asker can take responsibility to keep the site clean and delete "beginners mistake". I believe we don't live in an ideal world, though.

Comment: In the case of `int(num)`, some beginning python programmers would expect it to *change* `num` to an integer. In this case, rather than simply a typo, I think that they have some basic misunderstanding of the semantics of function calls. I agree that closing questions like that makes sense, but calling them typos is a bit of a stretch.

Comment: Do we *want* to close "fundamental/basic misunderstanding" questions? I think I've read somewhere that the policy is "all questions are allowed, no matter how basic"SW*FRLG

Comment: I remember a question which had a typo but it indeed found a bug within a C++ compiler.

Comment: @user202729 But that's not what's being discussed. I'm all for not closing questions based on a basic misunderstanding. However, for many questions it's clear that the user do understand, but they simply forgot something. Another example of this could be forgetting to call a function. It could be a legitimate question, but if the user show in their example that they clearly know how to call a function, I'd say that it should be closed. Such question won't help anyone other than the user. My question is whether I should flag it as a typo or not.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There is a particular common situation where I use it.

- Someone posts their broken code asking for help.
- Someone in a comment says "Isn't it as simple as changing [x]".
- Original posters says "it worked! Thanks!" - and scurries off

If a simple typo problem was resolved in comments, then an answer won't help anyone else as there is no specific problem. Vote to close, probably downvote because such questions are likely not going to be of any redeeming quality, cleanup in aisle 5.

Of course there is the "not reproducible" part of the equation. Those are the easiest to identify. Person has a problem, people in comments are confused as everything looks fine, person comments back "I rebooted the server and then it worked..." - not reproducible. There may be a problem with the server in that hypothetical scenario but that is out of scope.

Answer (score 7):

You can use this close reason for question where the answer applies only to the question asker and is not going to be helpful to anyone else. These usually are the problems where the problem was caused by missing semicolon, incorrect indentation, extra character, upper/lower case mismatch, etc.

Neither of the examples you showed in the question is a typo. They describe a very specific problem. Even if OP was to rewrite the code again they wouldn't find the mistake. This is not a typo.

You can also close questions using this reason when the question asks for debugging help and the code in the question works when you run it locally. This implies that the problem is not the code OP is showing to us, but rather something else.

If a problem seems so simple that you can answer it in comments, then it means that the question is likely a duplicate. However, we trust the judgement of each individual to identify whether the problem is localized only to OP's code or the same problem can be encountered by other people. Therefore, some typo questions are still on-topic, but it's likely they can be closed as a duplicate.