# What should happen to questions about simple programming errors?

Tags: discussion, questions

For instance, this one: [Same Iteration Yields Different Results In Different Codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66288087/same-iteration-yields-different-results-in-different-codes?noredirect=1#comment117194702_66288087)

The OP simply had their print statement in the wrong place.

I don't think it will be valuable to anyone else -- its a very specific problem.

I suppose I could downvote as 'not useful', although it wasn't a badly asked question.

Should the OP be encouraged to delete questions like this?

I have read [What can I consider a typo?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405336/what-can-i-consider-a-typo) but I didn't think the answers provided a consensus as to what should be considered a typo.

Comment: "*I don't think it will be valuable to anyone else*" [does this apply?](https://i.imgur.com/bHCVDE3.png)

Comment: Sounds like you think it should be closed as a typo have you voted/flagged the question in that way?

Comment: So the consensus is that minor logic errors count as typos?

Comment: "*While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers.*"

Comment: How does your question differ from the [referenced one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405336/what-can-i-consider-a-typo)? From my understanding, both questions asks whether particular "simple programming error" could be voted as "... caused by a typo". The only difference is an example of that "simple programming error". Of course, that difference could lead to different answers... But are you sure you want to ask a new **similar** question before the older one has a "consensus"?

Comment: @Tsyvarev I will close this as a duplicate in favour of that question.  I wasn't really sure how to *bump* that question. I admit that the top voted answer supports the consensus in comments here that logic errors can be considered typos.

Comment: Such logic errors are not typos.  No matter how much some might want to decorate such incompetence, the lack of minimal understanding and inability to manage even simple debugging and bug analysis remains:(

Comment: @MartinJames there is [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313884/closing-as-a-mental-typo) old open feature request to add minor logical errors to the close reason description.

Comment: A very well written question can certainly be "not useful". You aren't judging the presentation quality but the underlying problem represented

Comment: The question you should ask yourself is very simple: **are others likely to have this problem in the future?** If so, it's a valuable addition to our knowledge base. If not, then it's probably something you should vote to close as a typo/non-reproducible. See also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348025/resolved-in-a-manner-unlikely-to-help-future-readers/348033#348033

Comment: @CodyGray We also need to ask: would someone with the same problem be able to *find* the question? Plenty of questions that we close as typos are due to common kinds of mistakes, but because the original OP can't identify (or misidentifies) the cause of the problem, such questions are almost impossible to search for, unless by some fluke the new OP writes virtually identical code. As Shog9 says in the link, they're "questions whose root-cause arose from a mistake that cannot be identified (and thus whose solution cannot be used) by future readers, *even those making the exact same mistake*".